# Send client certificate to my origin server with cloudflare

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, client-certificates, envoyproxy, mtls

I wanna secure my microservices communication with client certificate. I generated a client certificate in cloudflare dashboard and added a subdomain (y.xxx.com) to dns with Full (strict) mode and enabled mTLS for subdomain (y.xxx.com).
I send client certificate with domain (y.xxx.com) but I can not access to client certificate in my reverse proxy (envoy). So I guess cloudflare does not send client certificate to my origin server.
How can I send client certificate to my origin server with cloudflare?
I try do this by workers. but I couldn't.